# Examples of modern hash tables

Tags: hash

I did some readings about hash tables recently. Many of them have different worst-case lookup time. In theory, the perfect constant lookup time is O(1). I want to understand more about hash table by inquiring:

1. Example of **well-known and modern** hash table algorithms, e.g. Cuckoo?
2. Their worst-case lookup time.
3. Current most popular hash table in database indexing area?

Comment: How is this related to security? Maybe you're looking for [CompSci](https://cs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: This is a question for Stack Overflow